# Error : Not find Module TestCafe in Angular

Tags: angular, automation, installation, automated-tests, testcafe

Here i have attached the screenshot of my error while i was compiling my **Angular** application.

I had install the **TestCafe** in my project **globally** but still this error is occurred so please give me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Could you provide a simple example in which I can reproduce the problem on my computer?

Comment: Which type of Example i can provide you ?? Can you explain it ??

Comment: You can simplify your current application's project, so we can see the same issue on our side and debug it. Running testcafe with a regular Angular project is working fine. It seems that your project is configured in some manner that does not allow you to run testcafe.

Comment: I am running on the angular 7 and while installing it will display the error in the above screenshot i had mationed

Comment: It is very difficult to provide any help without the detailed information about this issue, so please prepare a sample Angular project which will help us reproduce the issue on our machines. I should note that it's very important to share your test code, because it is possible that the cause of the issue lies there.

Comment: I had already created the new application and when i entered the command for install the testcafe and create the test and run the ng serve command it was displayed this error.

Comment: You can share the created application with us by sending it at support@devexpress.com, so we can take a look at it.

Comment: ok i will share the link for it

Answer (score 0):

Only we need to write the below code in the section of  **devDependencies** in the **package,json** file

```
"devDependencies": {
"testcafe": "*"
}
```

Now we need to write this command again.

```
npm install
```